# Is my Gmail account compromised?

Tags: gmail

I'm getting weird emails that I signed up for some service that I never heard of and the email is being sent to a `someweirdname@mywebsite.com` address.

I never created such account. I checked at admin.google.com but that user does not exist! So what the hell is going on? Why am I getting random email to an email at my domain that doesn't exist?

Has my email been compromised?

Comment: Could just be spam. Why are you worried?

Comment: Is that a Google Apps account? If yes, it could be that there is a [catch-all](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en) setting turned on somewhere.

Comment: @Alex should I disable it?

Answer (score 2):

No. A bot most likely picked up your email address and is just sending you emails to see if you'll fall for some sort of a trick into getting you to click on a link in the email.

Just mark it as spam. Also, you can check where you are logged into Gmail by click "Details" as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Gmail footer]

And if you choose to log out of all the other locations, you can rest assured nobody else is logged in.

Additionally, you can change your password as well.

Comment: And, as for the `someweirdname@mywebsite.com` address, it could be that your real address is `BCC`ed, so it appears that you are receiving mail for `someweirdname`.